# primefaces handleFileUpload doesn't trigger

Tags: file-upload, primefaces

I'm trying to implement a page with primefaces fileUpload but my handleUpload function isn't triggered.
My xhtml:

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <p:panel id="uploadFormPanel" header="File upload">
     <h:panelGrid columns="2" style="margin-bottom:10px" cellpadding="5">  
         <h:outputText value="#{criteriaTranslation.questionaireFile}:" />
         <p:fileUpload update="uploadMessages"   
                       fileUploadListener="#{critereCSVImporter.handleFileUpload}"
                       mode="advanced"
                       allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(csv)$/"/>  
    </h:panelGrid>
    <p:growl id="uploadMessages" showDetail="true"/>
  </p:panel>
</h:form>
```

My backing bean:

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class CritereCSVImporter {

@Inject
private CriteriaBL criteriaBL;
private String OCRMODE;

public void handleFileUpload(FileUploadEvent event) {
    System.out.println("handle");
    InputStream inputStream = event.getFile().getInputstream();
}
```

My web.xml:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>
        org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter
    </filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>PrimeFaces FileUpload Filter</filter-name>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
</filter-mapping>
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: what primefaces version are you using?

Comment: did you placed 
commons-fileupload and commons-io jars in your lib folder ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place commons-fileupload and commons-io jars in your lib folder

[Apache Commons FileUpload](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload)

[Apache Commons IO](http://commons.apache.org/io)